# Enzyme Invariant Violation: React HOC as a function not class

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying to test functions being called inside an HOC that handles HotKey combinations (simulate('keyDown').  However, I am not understanding how Enzyme handles this type of scenario.

I have many components that are wrapped by an HOC like so:

```
class RealComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return (<div>The views</div>);
   }
}
export default Hoc(RealComponent);
```

and the HOC itself is:

```
const Hoc = RealComponent => {
    class Hoc extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        methodGetsTriggered() { // <this is the method I want to test when simulating keyDown
            this.childComponent.methodToCall();
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <RealComponent
                    ref={component => (this.childComponent = component)}
                    {...this.props}
                />
            );
        }
    }
    return Hoc;
};

module.exports = Hoc;
```

When I try my test with

`shallow(Hoc(<RealComponent theProps={things} />),{context});`

I receive the error

> Invariant Violation: ReactShallowRenderer render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a component class, make sure to instantiate it by passing it to React.createElement.

I am trying to test the `methodGetsTriggered()` in the Hoc.

Comment: What about `const HocAppliedComponent = Hoc(RealComponent);` and `shallow(<HocAppliedComponent theProps={things}/>, {context});`?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that suggestion in another post, but it's the same result.

Comment: I think more details of your implemention are needed. I tried to re-create your setup and with @Oblosys suggestion (but without props and context, since I don't know what are there) all works fine. Like this `shallow(<HocAppliedComponent />)`